# Dropdown list not displaying on html from database

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to fetch data from rest api to display in drop down list.
I am able to call rest api but which is getting data but does not display drop down in html.
Below is my html code

```
<select>         
<option *ngFor="let discountlist of discountlists" [value]="discountlist.id">{{discountlist.discount_code}}</option>
</select>
```

Below is my component class where i am calling in ngOnInit function,

```
  this.autopostService.getcarDiscountSchemesList(this.myDate).subscribe(
      (data: Autodiscount) => this.discountlists = data,
      error => this.error = error
    );
```

Below is the data i am getting from rest api

```
[{"discount_code":"SAVE20","id":"1"}]
```

When i inspect in browser its show below api response,
[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzkua.png)

Below is my class file Autodiscount,

```
export class Autodiscount {
  id: string;
  discount_code: string;
  discount_on_All: boolean;
  discount_on_car: boolean;
  discount_on_cars: boolean;
  discount_on_part:[];
  discount_on_parts:[];
  discount_price:string;
  end_discount_date:string;
  start_discount_date:string;
}
```

Comment: Type Mistake Brother  [value]="discountlist.id" > {{discountlist.discount_code}}

Comment: is `Autodiscount` a list as a type? Or did you mean to use `(data: Autodiscount[]) => ...`. Don't know if it solves anything though.

Answer (score -1):

First check if data is coming from API by `console.log`

```
  this.autopostService.getcarDiscountSchemesList(this.myDate).subscribe(
  (data: Autodiscount) =>{
      this.discountlists = data;
      console.log(this.discountlists);
   }
  error => this.error = error
);
```

Then try writing it like this :

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let discountlist of discountlists" [value]="discountlist.id">{{discountlist.discount_code}}</option>
</select>
```

**Working Demo**: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twnztw)

Comment: @nilay then can you share the data you are getting from API

Comment: @nilay added a demo, pls check

Comment: @nilay does demo is what you want or something else

Comment: the demo is correct but i cannot bing rest api data to html

Comment: @nilay Did you test your rest API ?

Comment: @nilay add console.log as shown in answer and tell are you seeing any output.